# How to get a type from other type (C++ template metaprogramming)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am fairly new to c++ template metaprogramming and trying to do the following things. Let us say I have a custom template class like this

```
template<typename Parameter>
class MYCLASS {
public:
    Parameter parameter;
    //Do something with it
};
```

Now in order for the user to instantiate the class, he/she needs to do

```
#include "other.h" //A header from other libraries
MYCLASS<other::someclass> myclass; //Suppose there is a class called  other::someclass in the "other.h"
```

I want to spare the user the problem of finding the header, and I want to try to use metaprogramming, with something like this

```
template<typename Type>
struct get_right_type_impl{
    //Do something here
};

template<typename Type>
using get_right_type_ = get_right_type_impl<Type>::type;
```

where get_right_type_ should return another type. For example, it should take a double parameter and return a other::someclass, and therefore the class definition should look like

```
template<typename Type>
class MYCLASS {
public:
    get_right_type_<Type> parameter;
    //when Type==double, get_right_type_<Type> should be equivalent to other::someclass
};

//Now one can use instantiation like this
MYCLASS<double> class;
```

I have tried something, mostly follow [this](http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html). While I think I get some of the article, I did not cook up the example which usually has the compile problem around usage of typename. After reading some answers from this forum, I get even more confused and am not sure whether this is even possible in our case, as I have not found exact solution from googling either.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Is your problem just the `typename` compiler error? `using get_right_type = get_...<Type>::type;` should be `using get_right_type = typename get_...<Type>::type;`.

Comment: There are other compile errors. I will edit it a little bit. Thanks for the help~

Comment: Yep. That is very stupid question. That is the typename problem.......Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename Type>
using get_right_type_ = get_right_type_impl<Type>::type;
```

Consider what the compiler thinks when it sees this. It has not clue whether `::type` is some variable or some type alias! You need to specify to the compiler that "Hey, I am saying 'type' is a typename, so use it that way". Hence the use of `typename` keyword to explicitly say that what follows is a type.

Moving on, `get_right_type` will basically need to be a type to type map. It's fairly easy to do this.

```
template <typename T> struct get_right_type;
template <> struct get_right_type<double> { using type = class_for_double; }
template <> struct get_right_type<int> { using type = class_for_int; }
```

Consider the above type mapping are in some header say 'common_mapping.h'.
You can do the following:

```
#include "common_mapping.h"
get_right_type<int>::type a;
```

Comment: AHHHHH, it worked and I understand. I am sorry this is really a stupid question.........